# How to render product list in my custom widget

Tags: magento2, magento-2.3

I am creating my custom module for magento 2.3 and I've faced an issue with widget.
I have created my widget type and when I include it to homepage I have to see product list of products I've selected to render.
I want to use .../magento/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml as a template

The problem is that Widget class has to Extend Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template class, and to render ProductList I have to extend Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct.

Maybe someone could give me a piece of advice how to solve this problem.

Here is a part of my code

file my-vendor/my-module/Block/Widget/MyWidget.php

```
class PromotedWidget extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
      \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
         array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getLoadedProductCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('necessary_attribute', ['necessary_attribute' => 'attr_value']);
        return $collection;
    }

    public function toHtml()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml');
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

Comment: why exactly to you have to extend Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct? Is injecting it via DI not sufficient? and why do you need it in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not good practice to extend Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct class. If you want to load custom product collection and want it to work it same as product listing page, then I suggest you to create a plugin for Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder class in your custom widget as follows:

> Namespace\Modulename\etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder">
        <plugin name="Namespace_Modulename::custom_collection" type="Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder" />
    </type>
</config>
```

> Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Model\Search\IndexBuilder.php

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Model\Search;

use Magento\Framework\Search\RequestInterface;

class IndexBuilder {    
    protected $_request;
    protected $_categoryHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->_productCollectionFactory    = $productCollectionFactory;
        $this->_categoryHelper              = $categoryHelper;
        $this->_request                     = $request;
    }

    public function aroundBuild($subject, callable $proceed, RequestInterface $request) {
        $select = $proceed($request);

        $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
        $collection->addAttributeToFilter('necessary_attribute', ['necessary_attribute' => 'attr_value']);
        $getProductAllIds = $collection->getAllIds();
        $productUniqueIds = array_unique($getProductAllIds);
        $select->where("search_index.entity_id IN ('" . join("','", $productUniqueIds) . "')");     
        return $select;
    }
}
```

In addition, you can refer [this](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/Incorrect-product-count-in-layered-navigation-after-overriding/td-p/97756) link for more details.